# AJAX calls with web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

In my XHTML pages, we have a bunch of server side calls using AJAX. In a scenario like this, it seems that the javascript event `window.load()` happens before any of the service calls are completed.

If one wants to use the `window.load` event to determine:

1. if a web page loading is complete *or*
2. to compute total time it took to load a web page *or*
3. wait for web testing tool to perform next steps

What is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

After going through jQuery documentation, I've implemented the ajaxStop() event and that seem to do the trick.